# On Ubuntu 16.04 web server, second "<?" gives an error

Tags: 16.04, php, webserver, html

In an Ubuntu 16.04 local LAMP web server, running a '.php' script, the first '<?' is correctly treated but the second '<?' (after a first '?>') gives an error suspecting there is an XML instruction inside HTML (which is not allowed). This script run perfectly on a public webserver. All the web is in '/var/www/full-domain-name/'

The script starts with:

'<? php ' and a lot of php sentences.
At a certain moment (318 lines later), there is:
'?>'
'<html><head><title>Estació terme</title></head>'

'<body background="full-domain-name/imatges/estacio_terme.jpg">'

'<table>'

'  <tr>'

'    <td>'

'**<?**'

'include "ET_mostra_estacio.html";'

'//echo "<br>input=".$Inp;'

...

The result is:

'<html><head><title>Estació terme</title></head>'

'<body background="http://localhost/full-domain-name/imatges/estacio_terme.jpg" >'

'<?'

'include "ET_mostra_estacio.html";'

'//echo "<br>input=".$Inp;'

...

The second '?>' is signaled as error.

I'm sure there is something wrong, but I'm unable to find it. Please help!

Comment: Proper formatting is backquotes arround `inline code` and two lines of three backticks `\`\`\`` to bracket code blocks.

Comment: I'm sorry. The quotes are only to illustrate the example. In the true script they aren't. There is no ''' line. I wrote ... meaning a text not showed in the question.

Comment: You should have used one (one or more pairs, actually), this is how code blocks should be formatted:  https://askubuntu.com/editing-help